# WSO2 EMM - Email Configuration Issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

When I send the enroll invitation email to the user I got issue please refer the [Image1 & Image1] screen shot for your reference.

And also please find the below link[View the doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM220/General+Server+Configurations#GeneralServerConfigurations-WSO2EMMemailconfigurations) which I have referred to setup Email configuration in EMM.

Version I have tested in 2.1.1 and 2.2.0 Beta

Image1[image] 
Image2[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is probably due to misconfiguration of email template configuration located at "/repository/resources/email-templates" directory. It looks like you have accidentally changed the  xml element.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have analyzed above question in Stackoverflow.6 months ago someone already discussed regarding the email issue - [Setting Up Email Notification For Wso2EMM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098406/setting-up-email-notification-for-wso2emm) Please refer the link, As per their discussion the email issue is already in WSO2 EMM 2.0.1 version. I also checked in latest 2.1.1 versions I have faced the same issue. Is it will be fixed in upcoming version 2.2.0? WSO2 Team awaiting for your response.